# using regular expression in xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

I want to use regular expression in xslt 1.0

### Input

```
<book>
    <p>
        The clavicle is broken more <inlinegraphic></inlinegraphic>
        mad_2235.eps often than any other bone in the body
    </p>
</book>
```

### Output

```
<book>
    <p>
        The clavicle is broken more
        <graphic name="mad_2235.eps" source="ISBN" in-line="yes"/>
        often than any other bone in the body
    </p>
</book>
```

Thanks,
Muthu

Comment: Fine, what's the question?

Comment: I want replace <inlinegraphic></inlinegraphic>mad_2235.eps  to <graphic name="mad_2235.eps" source="ISBN" in-line="yes"/> here .eps with space is delimiter so any contetnt coming after the closing </inlinegraphic> tag till the delimiter should be placed in name attribute of graphic tag.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT 1.0 doesn't do regular expressions, but I don't think you need them in this case.  I would start with an identity transformation

```xml
<!-- copy everything from input to output verbatim, except where overridden
     by more specific templates -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

then override this with a template that matches any text node that immediately follows an `inlinegraphic` element and contains `.eps`

```xml
<xsl:template match="text()[preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::inlinegraphic]]
                           [contains(., '.eps')]">
  <!-- take everything before the first .eps as the graphic name -->
  <graphic name="{normalize-space(substring-before(., '.eps'))}.eps"
           source="ISBN" in-line="yes"/>
  <!-- and leave everything after that as normal text -->
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., '.eps')" />
</xsl:template>
```

And finally add a template to remove the `inlinegraphic` element itself

```xml
<xsl:template match="inlinegraphic" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this is removing the rest of the text after the inlinegraphic tag

Comment: @Muthu strange, that's what the `value-of` is supposed to handle.